# Jsoup extracting p,ul, h3 and img

Tags: java, jsoup

```
   String url = "http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/review-sony-playstation-4-does-greatness-await";
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
   Elements content = doc.select("#content p, #content table ul, #content h3");
   Elements img = doc.select("#content [src]");
```

Basically What I'm trying to do is extract the p, ul, h3, and img from the following url: http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/review-sony-playstation-4-does-greatness-await

The problem I'm facing right now is getting all the content to display one after another similar to the site's layout.

I've tried the for loop to generate the absolute img links but by doing so, the layout runs.

Below is the code I used:

```
for (Element bb : img)

String src = bb.attr("abs:src");
System.out.println(src);
```

Comment: Leaving out the braces for the `for` loop was intentional?

Comment: For this example, yeah.

Comment: What do you mean with "By doing so, the layout runs."?

Comment: Well previously I did not declare img. #content [src] was on the same line as the #content p, #content table ul, #content h3. Printing it out produced a layout similar to the site which I'm trying to get the code from.

However, I'm unable to get the absolute link this way hence some of the images refuse to appear. By creating a for loop separately, I'm able to get the absolute link BUT am unable to keep the same layout as the previous code as either the loop runs first to give me the links of the images or I'll extract the other content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extracting all of the Elements that you want, loop through and replace the src for all img Elements with the absolute url of the image. You can retrieve this with the [absURL()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl%28java.lang.String%29) function of the Node class in Jsoup:

```
String url = "http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/review-sony-playstation-4-does-greatness-await";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements content = doc.select("#content p, #content table ul, #content h3, #content [src]");

for (Element e : content) {
    if (e.nodeName().equals("img")) {    // if node is <img>
        e.attr("src", e.absUrl("src"));  // set src attribute to be absolute url 
    }
}
```

If you then print out content (e.g. `System.out.println(content)`) you will see that all of the Elements are still in the same order as they appeared on the original page, and the absolute URL has been inserted for all images.

For example (note that this is just a subsection of output):

```
<p class="rtecenter"><img src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/files/img/2013/12/rearports.jpg" width="700" height="232" title="The entire rear side is covered in cooling vents. This is also the first Playstation to ditch all analog connectors." alt="" /></p>
<img src="http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/files/img/2013/12/rearports.jpg" width="700" height="232" title="The entire rear side is covered in cooling vents. This is also the first Playstation to ditch all analog connectors." alt="" />
<p>Rather frustratingly, especially for a next-gen console that is expected to last at least the next five years, the PS4 doesn't support the Wireless 802.11ac standard, instead utilizing the older 802.11b/g/n network, and even then 5GHz bands are not supported! So you're stuck with&nbsp;2.4 GHz speeds. This makes a wired connection almost mandatory, as downloading games or even large update files over wireless can be extremely sluggish.</p>
<h3 class="page_title">&nbsp;</h3>
```

---

UPDATE:

Add this loop to remove the `<img>` elements from inside the `<p>` elements, but retain the `<a href>` elements:

```
for (Element e : content) {
    if (e.nodeName().equals("p")) {
        for (Element child : e.children()) {
            if (child.nodeName().equals("img")) child.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code. It worked partially. Right now some of the old non-absolute links still remains. This causes a "double image" problem whereby there are 2 of the same images but only able to view the one with absolute image :(. Really appreciate your effort thought ashatte.

Comment: @Wilson Is this happening for the same url you provided in your original question? If I loop through and print out all of the img elements after replacing the src with abs url, I find there are 17 images on that page and all of them have the abs url for me. Strange.

Comment: Hmm I found the problem. Apparently some of the <p> are extracting img files as well.

Comment: @Wilson Yes that makes sense. See my updated answer for another loop that will remove the <img> elements from inside the <p> elements, but still leave any text that is inside the <p>.

Comment: Great it worked! Another problem occurred again :( Now with the e.owntext, it removes all the href links.

Comment: @Wilson See my updated loop. It will remove only the <img> children from each <p>, leaving any other elements such as href links. Please accept my answer if this solved your problem.